# Can I still use rhc port-forward with openshift 3?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools

With `rhc port-forward` I can connect to the remote database of openshift, and with openshift 2 being discontinued soon, I'm moving to openshift 3. But I could not find a way to get `rhc port-forward` working with openshift 3 ande I'm not able to install openshift origin on my raspberry pi 3.

So I was wondering how or if it is still possible to use `rhc port-forward` with openshift 3. If that doesn't, how can I make [openshift origin](https://www.openshift.org/download.html#oc-platforms) work on my raspberry pi 3?

**EDIT**
For anyone wondering how I got it to work: [How to get openshift oc command working on Raspberry pi 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46391139/2890156)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openshift 3 uses the `oc` command line tools instead of `rhc`. You can find the documentation of using `oc port-forward` [here](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cli_reference/basic_cli_operations.html#port-forward).

Comment: As I stated in my question, I could not get `oc` work on my RPI3

Comment: Ahh, `oc` is just the command line tool. OpenShift Origin is the open source software for running an Openshift server. From my understanding, RPi's run a 32bit OS. The last version of OpenShift to include 32bit command line tools was 1.5.1. You can download the 32bit command line tool [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.5.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-32bit.tar.gz)

Comment: Getting the error `./oc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`, trying to build the source manually now