# How to get openshift oc command working on Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: openshift, raspberry-pi3, openshift-origin

I'm trying to compile openshift [origin source](https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/v1.5.1) on my raspberry pi 3 but it keeps timing out.

[image]

The tutorial I'm following is from [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v1.5.1/CONTRIBUTING.adoc#openshift-development)

Reason I'm doing this is because I get the error

> ./oc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

when I download the file directly from [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v1.5.1) and use it.

So can anyone tell me what I have to do to make this work or how I fix the errors?

With openshift 2 being discontinued soon, I cannot access my application with `rhc` anymore (which works fine on my RPi3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi probably does not have enough RAM to compile `oc`.  I suggest running something like the following on your primary machine and copying the resulting binary to the Pi:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 GOARM=7 go build -v -tags 'include_gcs include_oss containers_image_openpgp' github.com/openshift/origin/cmd/oc
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, here's the answer for others and for future reference.

1. Clone the repo
2. Switch to tag v.1.5.1
3. Install go for windows and configure environment variables

   - Had to move the repo to the GOPATH and create some folders in it (src/github.com/openshift/origin)
4. Open terminal and set some values

   - set CGO_ENABLED=0
   - set GOOS=linux
   - set GOARCH=arm
   - set GOARM=7
5. Use the command `go build -v github.com/openshift/origin/cmd/oc`

And you will get an executable that is usable for the RPi 3